# How to use input letter to print on the screen the list of employees whose name starts with that letter and their corresponding info

Tags: c, file, structure

The problem consist of 2 array structures and each task is broken down into functions. I need help with the function that would ask the user for a letter and print on the screen the list of employees whose name starts with that letter.

These are the files. 
employees.txt

```
Jimmy OBrien 1234567D Irish 40 1 2
David Keogh 3234567F Irish 61 0 0
David Hanahoe 5234567G Irish 48 1 2
Tom Byrne 6234567N Irish 62 1 4
Thomas Collins 8234567B Irish 35 0 0
Aoife Murphy 4234567F Irish 63 1 3
Joan OBrien 5234567M Irish 36 1 1
Maria Ionescu 7734567E Romanian 43 1 2
Celine Keogh 2254893R Irish 38 1 0
```

benefits.txt

```
1234567D 37500 20 10 0
3234567F 40000 20 10 0
5234567G 42000 20 10 0
6234567N 45000 20 10 0
8234567B 47000 20 10 0
4234567F 50000 20 10 0
5234567M 55000 20 10 0
7734567E 60000 20 10 0
5234997P 75000 20 10 0
2254893R 75000 20 10 0
```

```c
void input_letter()
{
    char letter[1]; 
    int i; 

    printf("Please enter a letter of a employee. \n "); 
    scanf("%c", letter); 

    printf("\nNAME\tSURNAME\tPPS\tSALARY\tPENSION\tALLOWANCE\n");

    for(i = 0; i < no_emplo; ++i)
    {
        if(strcmp(emplo[i].name, letter) == 0) {
            printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
            emplo[i].name, 
            emplo[i].surname, 
            emplo[i].PPS, 
            bene[i].salary, 
            bene[i].pension, 
            bene[i].allowance); 
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code, it only prints out the first 2 print functions and doesn't even allow me to input a letter.

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to read one letter from stdin. But your variable `letter` is an array of size 1. It is not long enough to store a string of length 1 *and* the terminating `'\0'`, so it can't be used with the `%c` format specifier.

Why don't you simply use a `char`?

```
void input_letter(void)
{
    puts("Please enter a letter of a employee."); 

    char letter;
    if (scanf(" %c", &letter) != 1) {
        fputs("Input error!\n\n", stderr);
        return;
    }

    puts("\nNAME\tSURNAME\tPPS\tSALARY\tPENSION\tALLOWANCE");

    for(size_t i = 0; i < no_emplo; ++i)
    {
        if(emplo[i].name[0] == letter) {
            printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
                   emplo[i].name,
                   emplo[i].surname, 
                   emplo[i].PPS, 
                   bene[i].salary, 
                   bene[i].pension, 
                   bene[i].allowance
            ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You submitted your answer a second before me :)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider these changes:

```
void input_letter()
{
        char letter;
        int i; 

        printf("Please enter a letter of a employee. \n "); 
        scanf("%c", & letter); 

        printf("\nNAME\tSURNAME\tPPS\tSALARY\tPENSION\tALLOWANCE\n");

        //Prints the table 
        for(i=0; i<no_emplo; i++)
        {
                if(emplo[i].name[0] == letter) {
                        printf("\n%s\t%s\t%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
                                        emplo[i].name, 
                                        emplo[i].surname, 
                                        emplo[i].PPS, 
                                        bene[i].salary, 
                                        bene[i].pension, 
                                        bene[i].allowance); 
                }
        }
}
```